# Interprocess communication and data sharing

Tags: java, c++, pipe, shared-memory, interprocess

I have Programm A (written in C++/Qt) and a Programm B (Java)[it starts Program A]. Everyone has the pid of the other. Now I need to implement a sharing of Informations and methods. But I don't know what the best solution can be. This will be a little animation program, so there is a lot of data that needs to be shared (timeline, 3D-Objects, Meshes, Graphs, ...)

My Ideas:

1. create with JNA a surrounding, and the Java program starts the program with a method in the library inside of a new process/thread.
2. or the same with JNI
3. or implement this with two pipes/streams (but I think, this will be complicated with many pieces of information, but if it is not, I'm open)
4. or with something with shared memory

The problem:

I have no idea what the best solution is and how I can implement that (I know how I can do that with pipes). Can anybody help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Implement a pipe.

Comment: And why is that a good solution?